# How to use intent.setData() for changing system settings?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I discovered this code online that sends the user directly to the where they need to change the app's system write settings:

```
Intent writePermission = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
writePermission.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(writePermission, 4);
```

I want to do the same thing but for an accessibility service. I have this code here but it's lacking the second line of the above code that sends the user to the needed service:

```
Intent changeSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(changeSettings, 2);
```

I want to send the user directly to WindowChangeDetectingService rather than have them look it up in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I discovered this code online that sends the user directly to the where they need to change the app's system write settings

That optional `Uri` is covered in [the documentation for that `Intent` action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS).

> I want to do the same thing but for an accessibility service.

[The documentation for `ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS) does not indicate that there is such an option.

Comment: :(  . Well it was worth a try